# Auto fill text inputs with user meta - email

Tags: wordpress, forms, input, metadata

I have a form that is not made using any plugins, I am looking for a way to see if a user is logged in, get their email address and then fill the field:

```
<tr><td><span style='nowrap:nowrap;font-size:15px;font-family:Arial;width:200px;line-height: 22px;'>Email'</span><br><input type='text' maxlength='100' style='width:250px;' name='Email'></input></td></tr>
```

I would use a plugin but there's gotta be a way to not use any plugins. And since the form isn't made with a plugin, CF7 dyanmic text extension won't work for me (yet i spose) or gravity forms.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get current get_currentuserinfo function for getting email.

check the code.

```
<?php   
 if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

          global $current_user;
          get_currentuserinfo();
          $user_email =   $current_user->user_email;

    } else{

        $user_email =  " " ;
      }
        ?>
    <input type='text' maxlength='100' value="<?php echo $user_email ?>" style='width:250px;' name='Email'>
```

Comment: I ended up with the php inline, is that bad? `<tr><td><span style='nowrap:nowrap;font-size:17px;font-family:Arial;width:200px;line-height: 22px;'>Email<span style='color:red;'>*</span></span><br><input type='text' maxlength='100' style='width:250px;' name='Email' value="  <?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$emuser = $current_user->user_email;
echo $emuser;
} ?>"></input></td></tr>`